# print matching word after a pattern using grep

Tags: linux, grep

```
grep '[branch "default"]' -A 3 config | grep -Po 'merge = \K\w+'
```

This grep command prints "master" which is what I want, is there a way to get it with single grep command instead of two grep's ? or any other solution?

file config has:

```
....
....
[branch "default"]
         remote = origin
         merge = master
....
....
```

Comment: Not with `grep`, possibly with `sed`, definitely with `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -zoP '\[branch "default"\].*\n.*\n.*merge = \K\w+' filename
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/\[branch "default"\]/{n;n;s/.*merge = \(\w\+\).*/\1/p}' filename
```

Output:

```
master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> grep -zoP '[branch "default"].*\n.*\n.*merge = \K\w+' filename